# how to fuse two GPS into navsat_transform?

Tags: ros, navigation, navsat-transform-node, navsat-transform, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, dear:

I wonder to know how to fuse two GPS into navsat_transform if I have two `imu`(imu0 & imu1), two `odometry` sources(odom0 & odom1), two `gps` sources(gps0 & gps1)?

As my understanding:

1. for `EKF_local_node`, just fuse imu0 & imu1, odom0 & odom1.
2. for `EKF_global_node`, fuse  imu0 & imu1, odom0 & odom1, and also feed the odom2 & odom3(generated by two gps sources gps0 & gps1, output of navsat_transform node ) into it.
3. launch `navsat_transfor_node_0` node, feed into imu0 & gps0 & output of step 2.
4. launch `navsat_transfor_node_1` node, feed into imu1 & gps1 & output of step 2.

Is this right? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

And another question:

a). In `step3` and `step4`, how to verify which imu sources should feed in?

I mean in step3, can I change imu0->imu1 and in step4 change imu1->imu0 or other options? how to determine this? I don't think in navsat_transform node it can support multiple imu imput sources.

b). should I turn on each UTM's `broadcast_utm_transform`?

c). And any other place should I pay attention to?

Thank you very much for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237968/how-to-fuse-two-gps-into-navsat_transform?/) by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2016-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(a) It's up to you. It doesn't take in multiple IMUs, no, but if you use the `use_odometry_yaw` setting and you DO NOT have `differential` or `relative` mode on for, it will take the fused yaw from the EKF (use `ekf_global_node`) and use that instead.

(b) That's up to you. Do you need it?

(c) Just keep referring to the tutorials. I also have a [branch](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/tree/281-documentation) with some improved documentation in the form of launch and config files.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0